# Can Arduinos keep a 500mu timer?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I need to output a serial message on a 500 microsecond interval (10 bytes), can be a little slower but no more than 1 milisecond between messages.

Can it be done with an Arduino? I know there is a delayMicro(), but not sure if it has the resolution.

Comment: Assuming serial data transfer to PC, it takes ~700 microseconds to send 10 bytes (i.e. 80 bits) at 115200 baud.  Check your numbers!  If you want faster data transfer, try SPI or ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to the delayMicro, but to the max speed of the Serial/UART driver, which is not documented, but according to some people it can reach 500 kbps.

However, 10 bytes, each 500 us (2000 Hz) means 10 * 11 (including some stop/start bit) * 2000 = 220.000 bits, so you have some headroom left. Maybe there is also some timing overhead.

Anyway, probably the only way to go is using an interrupt, and expect the Uno is not able to do anything else.

A better option might be to send less or send smarter (i.e. not 10 bytes, but maybe some compressed/binary form if not already thought about).

Comment: "but according to some people it can reach 500 kbps."  You can do better than that.  Per the datasheet, 2 megabits/second can be reached.  Table 24-7. Examples of UBRRn Settings for Commonly Used Oscillator Frequencies, shows 2 Mbps as the max rate achievable with 16 MHz clock.  The IDE only goes to 115,200 so you'll need to use a different serial program to see that data.  The fastest I've tested with is Serial.begin(250000);